# Relaying on typhoon in tests with "White-box" approach

Tags: objective-c, typhoon, kif, white-box-testing

I've got following solution for white-box tests:

- Typhoon - DI framework
- KIF - tool for interacting with UI

To test every single important edge case, i sometimes have to "stub" response from backend. 
I made it by patching component ( here is full description how it's done:[How to inject fake, stubbed or mock dependencies for Integration tests using Typhoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004010/how-to-inject-fake-stubbed-or-mock-dependencies-for-integration-tests-using-typ) )

so

in beforeAll method in KIFTestCase, HTTPClient was patched into FakeHTTPClient, and it gave me possibility to swap responses for particular requests.

> project architecture

Production code for app, was refactored in most critical places, but in some places i had to use defaultAssembly to get dependencies from graph, so almost every Assembly in app is now deafultAssembly.

And of course there are dependencies with scope TyphoonScoopeSingleton.

> problem:

After patching httpClient, those components with scope Singleton, are "refreshed" - init was called once again.

If i want to dynamically replace components in graph, for instance in beforeAll method, it is possible to do it with Typhoon without "refreshing" dependencies with scope Singleton?

Comment: From memory, I don't think it is possible to avoid reloading singletons, without a code-change to Typhoon. Even then, depending on what is being patched, the effected object graph would have to be reloaded.

Comment: @JasperBlues thanks for fast reply. Do you have any advice how to fix that?